# Docker Compose Links not working with Host mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Having issues getting docker links to work if I use "host" mode.  How do you access the other linked docker container if it is using "host" mode?

An example:

If I use these 2 compose files below, I can run the following:

> $ docker-compose up
>
> $ docker exec -it [CONTAINER ID OF REDIS1] bash
>
> $ redis-cli -h redis2 [OR redis-cli -h redis2-alias]
>
> $ PING  => you will get back PONG from redis2

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  redis1:
    image: "redis"
    ports:
      - "6379"
    links:
    - redis2:redis2-alias
  redis2:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.redis2.yml
      service: redis
```

docker-compose.redis2.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis"
    ports:
      - "6379"
```

however, if you change docker-compose.redis2.yml to use host mode.  when you try to connect to redis2 (from redis1)...it just hangs and never connects

docker-compose.redis2.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis"
    network_mode: "host"
```

> $ docker-compose up
>
> $ docker exec -it [CONTAINER ID OF REDIS1] bash
>
> $ redis-cli -h redis2 => this just hangs...never connects to redis2

how do you connect to redis2 (when it is in host mode) from redis1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Links are not supported with `--net=host`. Links are also deprecated (in philosophy) now. Prefer using a custom network.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Docker chose not to support this use case due to its complexity, see the [GitHub issue here](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/7066).